# Title for each subplot is cutoff in R

Tags: r, plot, oma

Despite my using the oma parameter in R, the title for each subplot is cutoff, is there some other parameter that can be used to display properly?

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(3,3),
          oma = c(0,0,2,0) + 0.1,
          mar = c(0,0,1,1) + 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: that works! can you put this as an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `par(xpd=NA)`: from `?par`,

> ‘xpd’ A logical value or ‘NA’.  If ‘FALSE’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the plot region, if ‘TRUE’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the figure region, and if ‘NA’, all plotting is
>             clipped to the device region.  See also ‘clip’.